# Setting the height of a button as a % of the window

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to set the height of a button as a % of the user's window. It seems this works :

```
#mybutton {
    padding: 10%;
}
```

But obviously doesn't quite achieve what I need (in addition, it's not responsive to the browser's size).

This doesn't work :

```
#mybutton {
    height: 10%;
}
```

I've also tried doing it with javascript (I really don't master it), but none of those two tries work either.

```
document.getElementById('mybutton').style.height = "10%";
document.getElementById('mybutton').style.height = window.outerHeight / 10;
```

How can I do that ?

PS : I've also tried with fixed values (100px) to see if I could change the height, and it seems I can't at all.

NB : I'd like it to be responsive to the user's window, meaning that if I reduce the size of my browser, the button should keep a height of 10% of it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF your element is a `span`, it won't work like you wish, but using a `div`, your code will work.

```
document.getElementById('b').style.height = (window.outerHeight / 10) + 'px';
```

Using css, your button will be `X%` of your `parent container`, so if you have a `parent container` with `300px height`, your button'll be `30px height` (using `height: 10%`).

You can also use the `vh` unit like @rnevius pointed out. But remember that a `span` won't work as you want, because it isn't a `block` element. (unless you force it by using `display: (inline-)block`).

Comment: Buttons in Bootstrap are always of the `inline-block` type...Which is why I didn't include that info in my answer. (This question was tagged with `twitter-bootstrap-3`).

Answer (score 5):

You can use [viewport units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths):

```
#mybutton {
    height: 10vh;
}
```

Viewport-relative lengths are [supported by all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

Comment: Thanks. I can't accept both answers, but I want to point for future viewers that this works.

Answer (score 3):

Though the answer has been selected I wanted to note three things here.

### Note #1

```
#mybutton {
    height:10%;
}
```

does not work because the height is relative to the parent and the parents, `html` and `body`, are not 100%. Checkout this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/3sLafksx/1/

### Note #2

The reason `padding` worked is because padding is not relative to the parent's height but to the parent's width. Which in case of a `div` element or plainly in the `body` is 100% of the window size.

**Refer:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/8211457/1799502 and http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_padding.asp

### Note #3

Using the viewport height <kbd>vh</kbd> and viewport width <kbd>vw</kbd> units is a very good idea but @rnevius was not kidding when he said all modern browsers, you need at least IE9 or Android 4.4

Answer (score -3):

Try putting a !important

```
#mybutton {
    height: 10% !important;
}
```

Comment: Yup, they work. Thank you for the suggestion though.